# Parallel.ForEach gives error

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I've been trying to search about what I can do for my Parallel.ForEach loop:

```
        selection.Words is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection;
        //range is supposed to be a word.Range
        Parallel.ForEach(selection.Words, range =>
        {

        });
```

This is the error I am receiving, The type arguments for method "**System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner, System.Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**"

I've been looking for a good time now, but all of them just show object.AsEnumerable() as the answer. selection.Words cannot be made into an enumberable, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see that the [`Words`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.words%28v=office.14%29.aspx) type is a non-generic enumerable -- so the compiler can't infer the generic type parameter for `ForEach<TSource>`.  You could make the collection into a typed generic collection by using [`OfType<Range>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(selection.Words.OfType<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range>(), range =>
    {

    });
```

Comment: selection.Words does not have a .OfType extension, unfortunately.

Comment: `OfType` is a extension of `IEnumerable`, so either `Words` is not a `IEnumerable` or you don't have `System.Linq` included in your `using` statements at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried specifying the type explicitly like this.

```
var list = new List<string>();
Parallel.ForEach<string>(list, (s) => s.Trim());
```

Comment: This just gives me a different error: "cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Words' to 'System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range'"